# Adding / removing claim from auth cookie for user that is already authenticated

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have a multitenant system (database per client), where one user can have access to multiple clients. After user authenticates, a cookie is generated for identity (I use ASP.NET Core Identity and Cookie auth for authentication).

Since this user can access data from multiple clients (different databases), after authenticating I check which clients can user access and provide view to select one client to proceed.

At this point I would like to store TenantId into cookie as claim, since I do not want to pass same information from client to server on each request. So I created a HttpPost API endpoint that looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<SetClientResponse> SetClient(SetClientRequest request)
{
    // To do:
    // Here I thought to store a SetClientRequest.TenantId property as claim in a identity cookie
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
var principal = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
var identity = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity();

identity.AddClaim(new Claim("TenantId", request.TenantId));
principal.AddIdentity(identity);
```

this works, I can see this claim into principal.Claims, but it is not stored permanently (on next request this claim is gone).

How to make this claim permanent in cookie? Or maybe there is a better way to achieve this? I do not want TenantId (and some other information) to be shown in url, I want to secure this data from malicious user as much as possible.

Comment: When you use `httpcontext` to add claim, It will only be added in this `httpcontext`, In my opinion, you can add claims in `SignInAsync()` method or just create an individual cookie to save this `TenantId`

Comment: @XinranShen Looks like SignInAsync() works, but with one caveat. I also need to provide it with AuthenticationProperties.IsPersisted value. Do you know if I can get from ASP.NET core Identity (or whatever) if authenticated user is persisted or not?

Comment: No, I don't find any other method can keep claim forever except `SignInAsync()`

Comment: @XinranShen I am not sure if you understood my question, so I will try again. When user Logs In, I have an option RememberMe, which is passed to SignInAsync with AuthenticationProperties.IsPersisted. Now, anytime I need to modify a claim in a auth cookie, if I use SignInAsync, I need to provide AuthenticationProperties.IsPersisted again.. Is there a way to find out values of AuthenticationProperties that have been set using previous SignInAsync (whle logging in)? Is it maybe stored somewhere by ASP.NET Core Identity? Or do I need to store this value manually in browser storage?

Comment: I got your point, I mean I don't find any other method can keep claim forever except `SignInAsync()`, If you want to save the configuration of `AuthenticationProperties.IsPersisted`, Maybe you can save it in cookie(i have never done this before). But in my opinion, I prefer to storing this value manually in browser storage.

Comment: @XinranShen Thanks. If you post SignInAsync as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I came to thought that Identity Claims are designed to store persistent claims about the user (or user group) but not the currently selected tenant which is a result of login. I got a problem with SecurityStampValidator which regenerates ClaimsPrincipal internally from ApplicationUser (i.e. from DB) without TenantId

Comment: I was wrong, in ASP.Net core some claims do come from sources other than DB. I had to implement `SecurityStampValidatorOptions.OnRefreshingPrincipal` handler in order to copy additional claims